# Is there anyway to format a set of items when format could also change

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, string-formatting

My problem is really more complicated but I have simplified it to allow easy explanation.

Suppose you need to write an string in different languages but you need to show a collection of items and possible the amount of this items, but you don't know the exact amount of them.

Let's take usernames, [user1,user2,user3,user4]

I want to produce this... "Hello to user1, user2, user3 and user4, our new 4 user(s) in last hour"

I want to define something like this... Hello to {item(1)} {, item(2..n-1)} and {item(n)} our new {count} user(s) in last hour.

The idea is to repeat items from 2 to n-1 to produce the comma separated values, and then add the fixed ones. {count} is a predefined variable, could be others (until now thinking that need to be fixed names).

The idea is to allow easy changes of formats to allow internationalization later or other things.

If you couldn't understand anything please ask...

What is the best approach to solve this in .Net?

thanks.

### Update

The main idea is to allow change the way the data is displayed, suppose I want now to show the user in different lines (I can modify the format in database for that message)

Hello to our new {count} user(s) in last hour {item(1.n-1) /br} {item(n)}.

Maybe the formatting is bad, I am just trying to get ideas.

### Update

Ok let's put another example to show what i am looking for, there is a collection of users, but actually i don't know how they should look, the format show be inside this tags {} or everthing else we can imagine. Another more complex example.

Hello to to our new {count} users.

```
{<div class="some class">item(2..n)</div>}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string template = "Hello to {NEWUSERS}, our new {COUNT} user(s) in last hour.";
string separator = ",";
//the two strings can be loaded from a config file

var userNames = new[] { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4" };

int count = userNames.Length;
if (count == 0) { /* No new users */ }
string newUsers = count == 1 ? userNames[0]
                     : string.Join(separator, userNames.Take(count - 1)) 
                                 + " and " + userNames.Last();
string greeting = template.Replace("{NEWUSERS}", newUsers)
                          .Replace("{COUNT}", count);
```

It's working fine if you change

```
string template = "Hello to our new {COUNT} user(s) in last hour: {NEWUSERS}";
```

Comment: Nice - that'd be what he's looking for.

Comment: How does this not get you that?  This answer is what you're looking for (or damn close)

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: I think my answer will output in his format.

Comment: maybe user could be separated by other format different than a comma, that's why i have not selected an asnwer.

Comment: Apparently he wants to be able to dynamically alter his algorithm and have the code be smart enough to keep up.  IDK - put the template in some config file??  (I up-voted your answer, btw)

Comment: @user468526: If the separator isn't a comma sometimes, you should specify it in your question. See my edit.

Comment: Dude - you have an answer above.  Any part you want to be changeable, like the first parameter to Join, just put in some configurable place like an AppSetting or something.  The code above should be able to get you going.

Comment: It really shows the data in the required format, but if you change the format it doesn't work, maybe the user names are inside a div tag with class and everything else.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var usernames = new [] { "apple", "banana", "cherry",  };

var count = usernames.Count();

var users = count <= 1
    ? usernames.FirstOrDefault()
    : String.Join(" and ", String.Join(", ", usernames.SkipLast(1)), usernames.LastOrDefault());

var prefix = count == 0 ? "No" : String.Format("Hello to {0} our {1}", users, count);
var suffix = String.Format("new user{0} in the last half-hour.", count == 1 ? "" : "s");

var result = String.Format("{0} {1}", prefix, suffix);
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but seems your are solving a particular format, now imagine that the format could change, please read my last update.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
List<string> UserNames;
string commaDelimited = "Hello to " + UserNames.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2) + String.Format(" our {0} new users in the last half-hour", UserNames.Count);
```

Comment: I think I'm still missing something though.  What else does this solution need to do?

Comment: Format is incorrect: Hello to {item(1)} {, item(2..n-1)} and {item(n)}

Comment: thanks, I updated the post based in your answers, the idea is to allow to change the format, your solution seems tied to an algorithm.